# How to consider both out puts in list

Tags: coq

I have less than relation between two index values and want to esteblish a relation between indexes. Have hypothesis - (nth i2 l d < nth i1 l d). There are two possibilities that (i2 < i1) or (i2> i1). I want to consider both cases. Plz guide me in writing this relation.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Nat.lt_gt_cases`, which proves `n < m \/ n > m` given `n <> m`. In context, that would look like this

```
Require Import PeanoNat.

Goal forall (d : nat) (l : list nat) (n m : nat), nth n l d < nth m l d -> True.
intros d l n m prf.
assert (ineq : n <> m). (* hypothesis for lt_gt_cases *)
{ intros ->.
  now apply Nat.lt_irrefl in prf.
}
destruct (proj1 (Nat.lt_gt_cases n m) ineq) as [ord | ord].
(* two goals left, one with n < m and the other with m > n *)
```